# Reasonable connectionTimeout for mysql connections?

Tags: java, mysql, hikaricp

I'm connecting to a `mysql` database using the `hikari` connection pool. Which offers a connection configuration property `connectionTimeout=30000ms`.

But in general: what is a good db connection timeout? I mean, 30s is pretty long, isn't it? Who would ever want to wait 30s to get the connection from the db?

Could you give any reasons how to set the `connectionTimeout`, or why a default of 30s could be a good use, also in production?

Comment: I agree that 30s is pretty long. It's especially bad because when your application receives a lot of requests in parallel, these add up and all have to wait. I recommend to use the "fail fast" approach and lower the connection timeout. Depending on the topology of your infrastructure, a connection should take no longer then 2000ms. To allow for hickups, I would set it to somewhere between 3000 and 10000.

Comment: There is no "good" timeout, only response times that can be considered "good". The timeout merely prevents a congestion (running out of threads) on the service side for db-interaction reasons.